# Downloaded Excel file with Macros is corrupted via MVC ajax

Tags: ajax, excel, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to download an Excel file from MVC Ajax call, but everytime it downloads, I cannot open the file, because it says it is corrupted.

Following is my Ajax call:

```
function Download() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/ExcelDownload',
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {            

        if (result !== null || result !== "") {
            $('<iframe src=' + result + ' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="myFrame"></iframe>')
                .appendTo('body');
        }
        //var iframe = document.getElementById('invisible');
        //iframe.src = result;
    },
    error: function (data) {

    }
});}
```

From my controller I call the action method like this:

```
string host = Request.Url.Authority;
        return Json("http://" + host + "/ExcelTemplates/EInvoiceTemplateNew.xlsm");
```

I am having macros enabled in Excel as well.

The file downloads properly but when I try to open it, it gives me a warning about being from a trusted source, and on clicking yes, I get another dialog saying "The workbook cannot be opened or repaired By Microsoft excel because it is corrupt".

Any help or suggestions or workarounds to make my code working.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Comment: Is this file stored on your server? Can you read the file into a byte[] and return it that way?

Comment: I have already made an excel file with macros and stored in my code folder. I am also using ClosedXML.Excel nuget package for manipulating sheets and cells. This file I call using "Server.MapPath", modify or fill values in sheet, and then download it.

Comment: My only suggestion, as I haven't worked with macro documents, would be to read the file into a byte[], then return it through FileResult. I remember a colleague recently having corrupt file issues until returning it like that. If you want a code sample, let me know and I'll type up an answer quickly

Comment: Yeah some code sample would be nice. If possible please include ClosedXML.Excel packages as I have used that.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to do a project and try the excel library right now as I'm at work, so I'm just doing this much quickly.

To start, I think you can get away from using `ajax` completely. Which is always nice because it's less code to maintain, you can use a normal anchor tag:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetExcelDocument", "MyController", new {id = Model.ExcelFileId})">Download</a>
```

This won't redirect the page, because the browser should interpret the content-disposition/Mime type, and just download the file.

Then you can try returning the file like this, where you first read the file (in this case into a `stream`, but you could do it as a `byte[]` as well as `File` has a overload for it), and then return it through your controller by using `File` and `FileResult`.

E.g:

```
public FileResult GetExcelDocument(int id)
{
    string filePath = GetPathToDocumentWithId(id); //However you get the excel file path
    return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath), 
                System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filePath),
                "filename.xlsm");

}
```

[This](https://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.html) website says that the content type/MIME of .xlsm is "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12", but I think `GetMimeMapping` should work.

Optionally, if you want the file to download in a new tab, you can set the `target` of the anchor tag to "_blank" and it should open a new tab and download the file there.

Let me know what the result is.

If you're set on using JQuery and ajax, I found this example which follows along your previous attempt:

From [Here](https://stopbyte.com/t/is-it-possible-to-download-file-using-javascript-jquery/59/5)

```
var $idown;  // Keep it outside of the function, so it's initialized once.
downloadURL : function(url) {
  if ($idown) {
    $idown.attr('src',url);
  } else {
    $idown = $('<iframe>', { id:'idown', src:url }).hide().appendTo('body');
  }
},
```